# Margin-bottom for <a> link elements

Tags: css, mobile-safari

I have a problem with `margin-top/bottom` on `<a>` elements - it doesn't seem to work.

This is the HTML code:

```
<div class="pages-link">
     <a href="#">1</a>
     <a href="#">2</a>
     <a href="#">3</a>
     ....
</div>
```

This is the CSS code:

```
.pages-link {
     margin:2em 0;
     word-spacing:.25em;
}

.pages-link a {
     background:#d7d7d7;
     border:1px solid #ccc;
     -moz-border-radius:3px;
     -webkit-border-radius:3px;
     -khtml-border-radius:3px;
     border-radius:3px;
     color:#333;
     padding:.3em .5em;
     text-decoration:none;
}
```

This is how the final result looks like. The problem is obvious, I want 5 or 10px of `margin-bottom` for the `<a>` elements, but the property doesn't get applied.

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You need to add `display: inline-block;` to your anchor selector. Anchors are by definition inline elements and do not accept width, height, margin etc until they are defined as block level or inline-block elements.

Comment: Be aware that the support for `inline-block` is relatively new in browsers, so in case you need to support older browsers refer to this link: http://caniuse.com/inline-block

Comment: True, I believe it appeared in IE7.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Kyle, it works! Sune, thanks for the extra info. I'm using this on a mobile-only theme, so it should be safe.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're better of doing `display:block;` and `float:left;` because `display:inline-block;` is not supported in all browsers.

Comment: Starting in March 2009, IE 8+ has supported `display: inline-block`, and most other major browser supported it prior to that (Chrome was notable for missing support until 2010).  While no CSS property is universally supported due to niche browsers, `display: inline-block` had been safe for over 2 years even as of this answer in 2012.  [See caniuse for details.](https://caniuse.com/#search=display%3A%20inline-block)